# Two raspberry pi with wifi communication and pc with wifi or ethernet network

Tags: networking, wifi, wireless, ethernet

I want to setup a network between two raspberry Pi and a pc. The Pi's should use Wi-Fi to communicate with each other, and for the pc it doesn't matter if it's with an ethernet cable or over Wi-Fi.

I tried this, and when the ethernet cable is plugged into the raspberry pi, everything is ok. It doesn't work without. What should i add/remove for this? I think that the reason is that it doesn't work is because there's a dhcp server somewhere on the LAN? Ideal situation is that what i want to achieve works without an external network. Just the PC to configure the pi over ssh and two pi's communicating over Wi-Fi.

https://github.com/Phoenix1747/RouteryPi

Comment: I think the easiest way of achieving this is to set up a **wifi hotspot** with one of your RPIs and to connect your other RPI and your PC to it. You can do this by simply using `hostapd`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some ideas to connect the devices. Just for this small amount of devices you could use peer to peer (P2P) network connections. But there is no much experience how to do it with a Raspberry Pi as seen at [WiFi Mesh Network Setup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/88586/79866) that does not show a real solution at this time.

So as already suggested in the comments you can configure one Raspberry Pi as wifi access point and connect the PC and the other RasPi to it. Because you do not need a wired ethernet connection there is no much trouble to realize this. Raspbian has everything "build in" so there is no need to install and setup additional software as explained on the setup from your link. Here you can look how to [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866). You can just finish the setup with section *Setting up a stand alone access point*. Then you have an access point that will do the job. If you need more later, then you can easily extend the setup following the next sections.